# Is it possible to turn a constexpr std::array into a std::integer_sequence?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

That is, given a `constexpr std::array<int,2>{1,2}` pass it to some function or helper class that would spit out the type `std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2>`?

It seems easy to jump from the type world to the "constexpr value" world (e.g., to do the reverse conversion), but hard or impossible to do the reverse.

Comment: I have a hunch that no, it's not possible because `constexpr` functions may still be called at runtime. However, this may be possible with `consteval` functions in C++20

Comment: Does your `array` have linkage?

Comment: @Davis - no. At least, I think not - it is created itself by a constexpr function based on template arguments.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: What determines the linkage is not how it is made but where it is stored (in a namespace, a class, a function, a class-type object).

Comment: @Davis - yes, but what I mean is "sure I'd like it to have linkage" but it is not obvious to me that it is possible given that it is not a global.

Answer (score 10):

It seems like you can do it in C++17, at the cost of introducing a lambda at the call site:

```
template <size_t N, typename F, size_t... indexes>
constexpr auto make_seq_helper(F f, std::index_sequence<indexes...> is) {
    return std::integer_sequence<int, std::get<indexes>(f())...>{};
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto make_seq(F f) {
    constexpr size_t N = f().size();
    using indexes = std::make_index_sequence<N>;
    return make_seq_helper<N>(f, indexes{});
};
```

Calling `make_seq` like this:

```
    constexpr std::array a{7, 15, 28};
    auto x = make_seq([](){ return a; });
```

Results in an `x` with type `std::integer_sequence<int, 7, 15, 28>`. I'm not sure if the lambda use can be removed.

Comment: Seems CLang cannot use an outside constexpr value without binding even though the standard allows such behaviour.

Comment: @youtaoguo - what do you mean by "binding" here?

Comment: I mean capture it in the capture list.

Answer (score 4):

If array have external linkage, you might do something like:

```
template <auto& Arr, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_seq_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using T = typename std::decay_t<decltype(Arr)>::value_type;
    return std::integer_sequence<T, Arr[Is]...>{};
}

template <auto& Arr>
constexpr auto make_seq() {
    return make_seq_impl<Arr>(std::make_index_sequence<Arr.size()>());
}

constexpr std::array a{7, 15, 28};

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]]auto x = make_seq<a>();
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::integer_sequence<int, 7, 15, 28>, decltype(x)>::value, "!");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/476a355e2f4f5719)

Or, with structure way, you might do:

```
template <const auto& Arr, typename Seq = std::make_index_sequence<std::size(Arr)>>
struct make_seq;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, const std::array<T, N>& Arr, std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_seq<Arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::integer_sequence<T, Arr[Is]...>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3690d0d5d5b5805a)

Comment: Internal linkage works just as well (since C++11, when it could matter here).  C++17 doesn’t require any.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++14 compatible solution.

A trick to "pass" a `constexpr std::array` (or any other struct/class object) as a template argument is to wrap it into a type:

```
constexpr std::array<int,3> a{7,15,28};
struct ArrayWrapper_a {
    static constexpr auto& value = a;
};

template<typename ArrayWrapper>
struct Foobar {
    // do stuff with ArrayWrapper::value
}
```

Then you can do something similar to BeeOnRope's answer to generate sequences:

```
template<typename ArrayWrapper, typename Sequence>
struct array_to_sequence_impl;

template<typename ArrayWrapper, std::size_t... indices>
struct array_to_sequence_impl<ArrayWrapper,std::index_sequence<indices...>> {
    using value_type = typename std::decay_t<decltype(ArrayWrapper::value)>::value_type;
    using type = std::integer_sequence<value_type, std::get<indices>(ArrayWrapper::value)...>;
};

template<typename ArrayWrapper>
using array_to_sequence = typename array_to_sequence_impl<ArrayWrapper,std::make_index_sequence<ArrayWrapper::value.size()>>::type;
```

Usage:

```
constexpr std::array<int,3> a{7,15,28};
struct ArrayWrapper_a {
    static constexpr auto& value = a;
};
using Sequence_a = array_to_sequence<ArrayWrapper_a>;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bMYuIM1rB9FxoiOT)